# Mann Whitney U revenue test effect size

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am looking for solutions around non-parametric hypothesis testing on revenue metrics in business settings. 
Currently I face with difficulties in finding the right way to make a Mann-Whitney U test results' effect size easily interpretable to the business. 
The intention would be to show the uplift of revenue for significant a/b tests. Translating the common language effect size or rank correlation to them is quite challenging and generally their interest is mainly towards the magnitude, the revenue uplift estimates.

Can you advise me any techniques?

Answer (score 5):

The common language effect size statistic † is an appropriate effect size statistic to pair with a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (WMW) test.  It is simply the probability of an observation in one group being larger than an observation in another group. That should be pretty easy for your audience to understand, but that doesn't mean that they care about such a statistic.

If you are really interested in the magnitude of the difference in revenue, WMW or the common language effect size statistic may not be what you're really interested in.  You might be more interested in comparing the means of the two groups or the medians of the two groups.  Or, honestly, if your audience just wants the projected difference in revenue, this value may be the only thing of interest, and a statistical test and effect size statistic may not be meaningful to them anyway.

---

† Also called Vargha and Delaney's A.

Comment: This concordance probability Sal mentioned is an excellent summary.  If you want to summarize MWM using odds ratios, means, exceedance probabilities, and quantiles, see Section 7.6 of [BBR](http://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf).

Comment: Thanks both; very valid points. From the business side, they are used to conducting t-test (on right skewed distribution) and calculate uplift from the mean in case of significant results. That's why id like to introduce a more robust testing framework that is able to give a solid uplift estimate. Maybe I should look at other techniques?

Comment: Also, I was thinking of calculating the delta between the observed U and the highest U (where p is .05) and using this delta to produce an uplift estimate. Would that make any sense?

Comment: Well, it may make sense to use a t-test on right- skewed data, depending on how skewed it is, and the sample size.... Comparing means may make the most sense in thinking about expected revenue.  But you might consider permutation tests on the mean.

Comment: I don't understand, and so  have no opinion on the difference-in-U idea.